# Firebase rule setting

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

We have a firebase structure as an attached image.

[image]

My current rules are

```
 "Games":{
     ".read":"query.orderByChild == 'email' ",
     "$gid":{
        ".read":true,
        ".write":true
     },
     ".write":false,
}
```

This helps to disable access to parent but when there is blank email id is passed it was fetching the whole database so is it possible to check the length of email using rules?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard for me to validate this answer blindly (so take it with a grain of salt), but I hope this will give you a directional help.

So the "download" in your case means the ability to read db.ref('/Games') should not be available, but a user (or certain users group?) should be able to read db.ref('Games/$gameId').

According to this article: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters

you can not achieve this with security rules restricting ".read": false at "/Games" level, cause this will prevent reads for any of the gameIds, since the security rule will cascade.

what you can do is to try using queries as way to "filter" as described in the article:

```
"Games":{
     ".read":"query.orderByChild == 'email' ",
     "$gid":{
        ".read": "query.orderBy("email") && query.equalTo === $gid",
        ".write":true
     },
     ".write":false,
}
```

So your DB query should be something like:

```
gamesRef = database.ref('Games').orderByChild('gameId').equalTo(20204315123456)
```

The above assumes that the gameId is also a property of each $gameId item inside Games list. The query above will check Games list for children whose property is "gameId" and that are equal to the value provided by the client (same as the key).

Hope that will help you.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I have added more information to the question. Anyone can only access data by executing https://path/Games.json?orderBy="email"&equalTo="gmail.com" or https://path/Games.json?orderBy="isActive"&equalTo=true

Comment: are you using firebase auth?

Comment: Yes we use firebase auth. We also don't want any users to access whole Games.json table

Comment: I see, so what happens if you apply .read policy to ensure read can only happen if query contains is required to have "equalTo" param and then user can only read particular $gid child when requested equalTo === $gid?? I updated answer.